# error connecting postgres with hasura docker on macos catalina

Tags: postgresql, macos, hasura

```json
{
  "exec_status": "FatalError",
  "hint": null,
  "message": "could not load library \"/Library/PostgreSQL/12/lib/postgresql/llvmjit.so\": dlopen(/Library/PostgreSQL/12/lib/postgresql/llvmjit.so, 10): Library not loaded: @loader_path/../..//opt/local/lib/libncurses.6.dylib\n  Referenced from: /Library/PostgreSQL/12/lib/postgresql/llvmjit.so\n  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:\n\tfile system relative paths not allowed in hardened programs",
  "status_code": "58P01",
  "description": null,
  "arguments": [],
  "path": "$",
  "error": "database query error",
  "code": "unexpected"
}
```

Postgres is installed as pgadmin in hardened runtime. Hasura docker container can not connect to postgres via docker-internal host.

Any help on how to solve this.

Comment: I'm seeing a similar error on Macos Mojave without any relation to docker, connecting from a standalone nodejs app to recently downloaded/installed latest postgresql server.

Comment: Seems related to https://www.postgresql-archive.org/BUG-16460-Error-when-executing-REFRESH-MATERIALIZED-VIEW-WITH-DATA-td6138684.html

Comment: This looks pretty much close to the issue I am facing. I finally had to install  postgres docker and that worked. Thanks for pointing this out.